# How to Change UIDatepicker Components from Day/Month/Year to Year/Month/Day

Tags: ios, iphone, date, datepicker, uidatepicker

Whenever we use `UIDatePicker` as Date Mode. it show as

[image: Image of DMY Mode DatePicker]

Where first we have to choose the Day/Month/Year (from left to right)

My requirement is Year/Month/Day (from left to right).

Comment: Look at this link. It might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345208/change-uidatepicker-order

Comment: With dateFormatter you can set or you have to make custom picker with UIPickerView.

Answer (score 3):

In Apple's documentation they specified that in `UIDatePickerModeDate`. The `DatePicker` displays months, days of the month, and years. The exact order of these items depends on the `locale` setting. An example of this mode is `[ June | 18 | 2013 ]`. But In device it display as `DD/MM/YYYY`. See [UIDatePicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) for more info.

So if you want to do it yourself you could create your own `UIPickerView` with the values you want.
It might helps you [create you own UIPickerView](http://gtiapps.com/?p=22)